# ReactHooks unexpected array behavior inside useEffect using setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Value named 'a' in the bottom code behaves not expectedly at local, not in static site.

I am expected that a is increasing by 100 per second, but increasing by 200 per second.

This problem is occurred when app is started using the next commands.

```
next dev
react-scripts start
```

How can I solve this problem? (And is this expected behavior of react hooks?) If possible, not using useReducer.

I have already read [the site](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies).

```js
import { memo, useEffect, useState, VFC } from "react";

const StateLearning: VFC = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState([
    [1, 2],
    [0, 4],
  ]);


  // This moved expectedly
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   const eff = setInterval(() => {
  //     a[1][0] += 100;
  //     console.log('add 100')
  //     setA([...a]);
  //   }, 1000);
  //   return () => clearInterval(eff);
  // }, [a]);

  // a[1][0] moves 0→100→300→500→……
  useEffect(() => {
    const eff = setInterval(() => {
      setA((prev) => {
        prev[1][0] += 100;
        console.log("add 100");
        console.info(prev)
        return [...prev];
      });
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(eff);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "10%" }}>
      <div>
        <div>
          {a[0][0]}, {a[0][1]}
        </div>
        <div>
          {a[1][0]}, {a[1][1]}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

P.S.

In addition, I also want to change value another function with like onClick.
the latter code is example.

```
…
// called by like onclick
const multiple = () => {
    setA((p) => {
      const newArray = [
        [
          p[0][0] * p[0][0] + p[0][1] * p[1][0],
          p[0][0] * p[0][1] + p[0][1] * p[1][1],
        ],
        [
          p[1][0] * p[0][0] + p[1][1] * p[1][0],
          p[1][0] * p[0][1] + p[1][1] * p[1][1],
        ],
      ];
      
      return [...newArray];
    });
  };
…
```

Comment: Not sure what is the issue with double update, but if you want to have true immutable state update you need to do `prev => prev.map((row, i) => i === 1 ? row.map((col, j) => j === 0 ? (col + 100) : col) : row)`. Otherwise you are mutating nested array w/o creating a copy https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wilson-fd89d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: When making like clocks, this problem is fatal. (I was confused that matrix was not expectedly updated in other case, so tested in simple case.) Your comment is very helpful and I really appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I created this sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-mahavira-co66j

Seems to me, it works

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const eff = setInterval(() => {
      a[1][0] += 100
      setA([...a])
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(eff)
    }
  }, [setA])
```

You do not need to make sure to use `prev` because `a` is an object in your case. The issue normally happens to a primitive value.

Comment: OP needs to use updater version form of `setState`. Having object as a value doesn't change why we need to use it. It currently works only because you are mutating nested array value w/o creating a copy with the original value captured in callback scope. If one have another way to edit values there will be whole bunch of an issues. https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-tdd-77xm2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this seems to work but I also want to  change value of 'a' with another function like onClick(matrix multiple). 
When setinterval function is moving, this func did not apply the change of onclick func.